# How can I get the resource count of the account and region in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ami

I was trying to get the resource(Snapshots,Images,Volumes,Instances) count of my account.I tried using the **GetDiscoveredResourceCounts** API but it does not give me Snapshots and Images count.

It only gives count of few resources.

How do I get resource counts for all the services including AMIs?